# Where was the formal definition of a limit first published?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta, math-history, mathematicians

I've read that Bolzano was one of the first to formalize a limit with the epsilon-delta definition, but I can't find a text of his that shows his definition. Does anyone know what publication the first epsilon-delta definition of a limit can be found in?

Comment: You could also try asking at the [history of science and math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523888/original-source-of-precise-%ce%b5-%ce%b4-epsilon-delta-formal-definition-of-a-limit

Comment: [*On the history of epsilontics*](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1502/1502.06942.pdf) by G.I. Sinkevich says *"In 1978, a reference book
[Alexandrova, 1978] was published where article ‘Limit’ reads as follows: “The
definition of a limit through $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ was provided by Bolzano (1817) ... Bolzano in 1817 and Cauchy in 1821 provided qualitative definitions
of a limit and definitions of a continuous function in terms of increments; ... Bolzano
never used this technique."*

Comment: The Bolzano (1817) reference is apparently: Bolzano, B. 1817. [Rein analytischer beweis des Lehrsatzes, dass zwischen je 
zwey Werthen, die ein entgegengesetztes Resultat gewähren, wenigstens eine
reelle Wurzel der Gleichung liege. – Prag, 1817](http://www.aleph.cz/sebestik/doc/Bolzano,%20Rein%20analytischer%20Beweis.pdf)// Bernard Bolzano (1781–1848).
Bicentenary. Early mathematical works. – Prague, 1981. – P. 417–476.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086080900361 An English translation of Bolzano's 1817 text (mentioned above by Henry). I might be wrong, but I think Bolzano gives the definition of continuity on page 162 of the linked text: "the expression that a function fx varies according to the law of continuity for all values of x inside or outside certain limits means just that: if x is some such value, the difference f(x + w) - fx can be made smaller than any given quantity provided w can be taken as small as we please."